# How can the directional derivative exist at this point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x, y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, with $f(0)=0$. It is easy to show that the directional derivative in the direction $(v_1, v_2)$ is $\dfrac {v_1v_2}{v_1^2+v_2^2}$, so it exists for every non-zero $v$. However, $f(x, x) = 1/2$, so if we intersect the graph of $f$ with a vertical plane passing through the line $y=x$, then I think we would see the following picture:

[image]

This function is clearly not differentiable at $0$. How can the directional derivative exist at $0$?

Comment: Generally, the existence of all directional derivatives does not depend on differentiability. But technically, the directional derivatives *don't* exist for this specific function because it is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: The directional derivative of this functiom at $(0, 0)$ in the direction of $(v_1,v_2)$ exists only if $v_1=0$ or $v_2=0$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy The directional derivative of this function in the direction of $v = (v_1, v_2)$ is $\dfrac {v_1v_2}{v_1^2+v_2^2}$, so it exists for all $v \not = 0$.

Comment: Your formulas are failing you, I think. I look at that graph and it is obvious that the directional derivative in the $(1,1)$ direction doesn't exist. How did you find your directional derivative?

Comment: The derivative is $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f(tv_1,tv-2)} t = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac {v_1v_2/(v_1^{2}+v_2^{2}} t$ right?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Oh I'm sorry I can't believe I did that calculation wrong.

Comment: @Arthur Oh I'm sorry I can't believe I did that calculation wrong. I just found it from the limit definition, but obviously messed it up.

Answer (score 1):

In general if all directional derivatives exist it is not enough to conclude that the function is differentiable. Hence, directional derivatives can all exist but the function cannot be differentiable. To show that all directional derivatives exist resort to the definition.

Edit: Removed incorrect info.

Comment: Sure. But the picture I provided would lead us to believe that the directional derivative in the direction of $(1, 1)$ should not exist at $0$. My question is, why is the picture wrong?

Comment: I just calculated the directional derivative at $(1,1)$, and it appears that I got limit as $t \to 0$ is $1/2t$ which doesn't exist. Your picture is correct!

Answer (score 1):

At $(0,0)$ the directional derivative of $f$  in direction $v=(v_1,v_2)\ne(0,0)$ is obtained by looking at the quotient
$${f(0+t v_1,0+t v_2)-f(0,0)\over t}={v_1v_2\over t(v_1^2+v_2^2)}={1\over t}\>{v_1v_2\over v_1^2+v_2^2}$$ and checking whether this quotient has a limit when $t\to0$. It is obvious that the limit does not exist when $v_1v_2\ne0$.

Note that  $f(t,t)={1\over2}$ for all $t\ne0$; hence the function $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.